# Correct way to pass string from web page, to php and then to Obj-C Command Line Tool

Tags: php, javascript, objective-c, encoding, shell-exec

**Preface:**

I've a web page with a form and a text field.

1) On submission, the text in the field is sent with ajax to a php script (with GET method).

2) The php script gets the text and passes it as a parameter to a shell tool.

3) The shell C tool parses **argc** into an array of unichars (actually an NSString in my current implementation)

(*4.. 5.. 6.. then the tool does his job, returns a result to stdout that the php script serves back as response to the web page...*)

I'm looking for the *correct* / *canonical* / "*unicode*" way to do each step so that: content is properly encoded and preserved, no security issues come out.

**What I'm doing now:**

1) (**JavaScript**) the text is retrieved from the form this way

```
theText = $('#theField').attr('value');
```

and sent to the server this way

```
httpReq.open('GET','myScript.php?theText=' + encodeURIComponent(theText),true);
```

2) (**PHP**) I get the text

```
$theText=(isset($_GET["theText"])?$_GET["theText"]:"");
```

I call the C tool

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/thetool -theText ".escapeshellarg($theText);
echo shell_exec( $cmd );
```

3) (**Objective-C**) I'm on MacOS X, so I take advantage of NSString and NSUserDefaults classes (but a plain C solution would be good for me as well, assumed that I'll end up with an array of unichars)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString       *theText =      [userDefaults stringForKey: @"theText"];
```

**Question(s)**

Is this the good way?

Is **escapeshellarg** alone safe when invoking shell_exec?

Am I going to lose some characters along the way if the user types something peculiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting from a competent reply, I've started making some **empiric** tests...

First I changed

```
echo shell_exec( $cmd );
```

to

```
echo $cmd;
```

to see what the command line invocation was turning out to be given various text entered in the form. It seem that **escapeshellarg** on the PHP side do a good job.

The text passed to the Tool seems to be always properly sealed between single quotes, with "dangerous" character well escaped. I found no way to tamper with the tool invocation.

Then I tested for the text passed to see if something was getting lost somewhere.

I set up the C tool this way and looked for the output

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString       *theText =      [userDefaults stringForKey: @"theText"];

    int i;
    unichar c;

    for(i=0;i<[theText length];i++)
    {
        c = [searchString characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger) i];
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Made various tries. It seems all ok. As the last test I entered a "MUSICAL SYMBOL G CLEF" in the form

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d11e/index.htm

It turned out to **correctly** end into the tool as a couple* of unichars

55348
56606

(* *being this a very special character whose code exceeds 65535 it need to be represented with a couple of surrogate unichars. This is the most edge case I found*).

Anyway as I stated at the beginning these are just empiric tests. I don't like to assume that sensible code is good just beacuse passes a dozen of test. I'd very happy to receive comments or suggestions (or warnings!).

I tested on Mac OS X - Firefox on the client side - Mac OS X - Mamp on the server side.